# how to parse and fetch this array flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, parsing, fetch, future

I found an example of event management that I would like to use this is my error

type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'

initially I have this array

```
 loadPreviousEvents() {
    mySelectedEvents = {
      "2022-09-13": [
        {"eventDescp": "11", "eventTitle": "111"},
        {"eventDescp": "22", "eventTitle": "22"}
      ],
      "2022-09-30": [
        {"eventDescp": "22", "eventTitle": "22"}
      ],
      "2022-09-20": [
        {"eventTitle": "ss", "eventDescp": "ss"}
      ]
    };
  }
```

I translate this using Future
this what i try

```
Future<List<Event>> getData() async {
            var url = 'xxxxxxx';
            var res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
            var mySelectedEvents = json.decode(res.body);
            for (var event in mySelectedEvents) {
              for (var eventInfo in event) {
                print(eventInfo["descript"]);
                print(eventInfo["title"]);
              }
            }
            // print(destinations);
            return mySelectedEvents;
          }
```

and my model.dart

```
class Event {
  String date;
  String descript;
  String title;

  Event(
    this.date,
    this.descript,
    this.title,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mySelectedEvents` is not a List hence you can't iterate over it.

To parse it, you could use a `forEach` or `map` on `mySelectedEvents` as follows.

```dart
void main() {
  const mySelectedEvents = {
      "2022-09-13": [
        {"eventDescp": "11", "eventTitle": "111"},
        {"eventDescp": "22", "eventTitle": "22"}
      ],
      "2022-09-30": [
        {"eventDescp": "22", "eventTitle": "22"}
      ],
      "2022-09-20": [
        {"eventTitle": "ss", "eventDescp": "ss"}
      ]
    };
  
  mySelectedEvents.forEach((k, v) {
    print("key-date $k");
    for (var e in v) {
      print('desc ${e['eventDescp']}, desc ${e['eventTitle']}');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I created two tables that reflect this array: event_date and event_list.How to retrieve the same information with a Future

Comment: Steps should be same. You can use forEach or map on `mySelectedEvents` after `var mySelectedEvents = json.decode(res.body); as Map<String, dynamic>`.

Comment: i  try   Future<dynamic> getData() async {
    var url = 'http://xxxxxx/getEvents.php';
    var res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var response = json.decode(res.body);
    Map<String, dynamic> mySelectedEvents = Map.fromIterable(response,
        key: (item) => item['date'],
        value: (item) =>
            {'eventDescp': item['descript'], 'eventTitle': item['title']});
    // print(destinations);
    return mySelectedEvents;
  }

Comment: [{id: 1, date: 2022-09-13, descript: 11, title: 111, id_event_date: 1}, {id: 2, date: 2022-09-13, descript: 22, title: 22, id_event_date: 1}, {id: 3, date: 2022-09-30, descript: 22, title: 22, id_event_date: 2}, {id: 4, date: 2022-09-20, descript: ss, title: ss, id_event_date: 3}]
I/flutter (16572): {2022-09-13: {eventDescp: 22, eventTitle: 22}, 2022-09-30: {eventDescp: 22, eventTitle: 22}, 2022-09-20: {eventDescp: ss, eventTitle: ss}}

Comment: i get no result